# Es posible agrandar el texto en la ventana dos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hice una calculadora en python que se abre en una ventana os usando la biblioteca del mismo nombre. Hay alguna manera de que el texto mostrado sea más grande?

Este es mi codigo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from math import *
import os
import time
import sys

salir = False

def input_str(msg="ingrese una operacion:"):
  while True:
        os.system('cls')
        cadena = input(msg)
        try:
           valor = str(cadena)
           if valor in ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','A','B','C','D','E','F','G']:
               return valor
               break  
        except ValueError:
               continue


def input_float(msg="Ingrese un número:"):
  """Valida que el input ingresado por el usuario sea un float 
     sino vuelve a solictar el ingreso"""

     while True:    
           os.system('cls')
           cadena = input(msg)
           try:
              valor = float(cadena) 
           except ValueError:
               continue
           else:
               return valor
               break

while not salir:

      numero_uno = input_float("introduce un número:")
      os.system('cls')
      operacion = input_str("\n\n'A' para realizar una suma(ejemplo: 9 + 6 = 15)\n\n'B' para realizar una resta(ejemplo: 7 - 3 = 4)\n\n'C' para realizar una multiplicación(ejemplo: 5 * 6 = 30)\n\n'D' para realizar una división 'normal'(ejemplo: 9 / 5 = 1.8)\n\n'E' para obtener el cociente(entero) de la división(ejemplo: 9 // 5 = 1)\n\n'F' para obtener solo el resto de una división(ejemplo: 9 % 5 = 4)\n\n'G' para elevar a una potencia(ejemplo: 3 ** 3 = 27)\n\nintroduce la operación a realizar:")
      os.system('cls')
      numero_dos = input_float("introduce otro número:")
      os.system('cls')

      if operacion == operacion.lower():
          if operacion == 'a':
              print(numero_uno + numero_dos)

          elif operacion == 'b':
              print(numero_uno - numero_dos)

          elif operacion == 'c':
              print(numero_uno * numero_dos)

          elif operacion == 'd':
              print(numero_uno / numero_dos)

          elif operacion == 'e':
              print(numero_uno // numero_dos)

          elif operacion == 'f':
              print(numero_uno % numero_dos)

          elif operacion == 'g':
              print(numero_uno ** numero_dos)


      elif operacion == operacion.upper():
            if operacion == 'A':
                print(numero_uno + numero_dos)

            elif operacion == 'B':
                print(numero_uno - numero_dos)

            elif operacion == 'C':
                print(numero_uno * numero_dos)

            elif operacion == 'D':
                print(numero_uno / numero_dos)

            elif operacion == 'E':
                print(numero_uno // numero_dos)

            elif operacion == 'F':
                print(numero_uno % numero_dos)

            elif operacion == 'G':
                print(numero_uno ** numero_dos)                    

        input()
        os.system('cls')
        reinicio = False
        while not reinicio:
              os.system('cls')
              reiniciar = input("desea realizar otra operación? si/no: ")
              respuesta = reiniciar.lower()
              if respuesta in ["si","no"]:
                  if respuesta == "si":
                     os.system('cls')
                     reinicio = True
                  elif respuesta == "no":
                       reinicio = True
                       salir = True
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow  en Español** tu pregunta debe ser sobre un problema sobre programación, mas sin en cambio lo que preguntas es una configuración. Lo que debes hacer es dar clic derecho sobre el icono de la ventana y luego en propiedades, ahi puedes configurar eso, aunque no trae mucho para configurar el tamaño de texto, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pero lo que quiero saber es si hay un codigo para eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma es jugar directamente con la API de windows, hay mucho ejemplos en la red, voy a adaptar un poco [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13940780/6836377) respuesta:

```
import ctypes

FW_DONTCARE       = 0
LF_FACESIZE       = 32
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)]

class CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("cbSize", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("nFont", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFontSize", COORD),
                ("FontFamily", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FontWeight", ctypes.c_uint),
                ("FaceName", ctypes.c_wchar * LF_FACESIZE)]


def set_console_font(font_name="Lucida Console", size=11):
    font = CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX()
    font.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)
    font.nFont = 0
    font.dwFontSize.X = size
    font.dwFontSize.Y = FW_DONTCARE
    font.FontFamily = FW_DONTCARE
    font.FontWeight = 400
    font.FaceName = font_name

    handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
            handle, ctypes.c_long(False), ctypes.pointer(font))

set_console_font("Lucida Console", 10)
```

Básicamente estamos invocando a la API [SetCurrentConsoleFontEx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex) que justamente configura el tipo de letra a usar en la consola, para eso necesitamos definir la estructuras `COORD` y `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX`, nos apoyamos en el módulo [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html) para todo los especifico a la Win api. En este ejemplo, simplemente invocamos `set_console_font()` que recibe dos parámetros, el FONT y el tamaño. Ten en cuenta que:

- La configuración es de la consola, al salir de tu programa esta se mantendrá. Se podría recuperar la configuración anterior pero es tema para otra pregunta.
- Esta solución obviamente es únicamente para aplicaciones de tipo consola en Windows.
- Los tipos de letra permitidos son los de tamaño fijo.